# moving across an image-that larger than screen size

Tags: iphone

I was asked in our company to take an image that is larger than iphone screen size, and it has to be a background screen, and  move (horizon) . so user see an image that moves from right to left by it self as a moving background.

i will be happy for any information on how to do that with xcode only .
i think i know how to animate images, but this shuld be bigger that screen size and move across one wide image as a camera ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UIScrollView` and add the image view as a subview of the scrollView.